# How to write and read Dimensional list array?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I use this code to be written in an array

But an error

```
void Start () 
{
    List<int>[,] li = new List<int>[8,5];
    li[0,0].Add(15);  //error in here
    Debug.Log(li[0,0][0]);
}
```

This is the error message

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   Word.Start () (at Assets/Script/Word.cs:19)

I wanted to use List and arrays allocated objects, but I found

`li[0,0].Add(15);`

A mistake, I made it the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a `List<int>` instance:

```
// create a list, add 15 to it and put the list into [0, 0] cell
li[0, 0] = new List<int>(){15};
```

Since `List<int>[,] li = new List<int>[8,5];` creates an *array only* and fills it with `null`s. You can create *all the lists* in a loop and then safely use `Add`:

```
   List<int>[,] li = new List<int>[8,5];

   for (int r = 0; r < li.GetLength(0); ++r)
     for (int c = 0; c < li.GetLength(1); ++c)
       li[r, c] = new List<int>();

   li[0,0].Add(15);
```

Comment: This working!Thank you: D

Comment: I think "List <int> [,] a = new List <int> [8,5];"has completed the instance, but did not,Thanks for your help and explanations :D